# how to edit this regx to detect full url

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am really new to Regex. almost know nothing. but I know js a bit.
I need to detect url in my website. This regx is great one i found.

`/((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?(([\w.-]*)\.([\w]*))/g`

But the issue is it only select part of url. I want to edit it so it select the whole link.
check this link: https://regex101.com/r/B5hYwv/2

[image: check image]

```js
// [EDITOR MADE THESE CHANGES]
//this code makes all urls clickable 
const re = /((http|ftp|https)\:\/\/)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/g;
let text = document.getElementById("links").textContent;
const matches = text.match(re)
console.log(matches)
for (let i = matches.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  text = text.replace(matches[i], `<a href='${matches[i]}'>${matches[i]}</a>`);
}
document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="links">
  Hello www.google.com World http://yahoo.com Here are some links https://www.google.com.tr/admin/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services https://google.com.tr/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services I want them to be converted to anchor tags
  http://google.com/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services ftp://google.com/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services www.google.com.tr/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services www.google.com/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services
  drive.google.com/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services

</div>
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/4XfRNi/1 would be a way

Comment: Modified from the dupe: https://regex101.com/r/4XfRNi/2

Comment: I am making js which convert all links to clickable url:
this is the JS i am using
https://prnt.sc/szxoze

i am using your regex in my website. I want to make all urls clickable. but with your regex output is https://prnt.sc/szxpwb

without js , my website is like this
https://prnt.sc/szxqmy

Comment: Please post actual code instead of pictures of the output

Comment: //this code makes all urls clickable

var exp = /((http|ftp|https)\:\/\/)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/g
var x =document.getElementById('msgContent').innerHTML.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
        document.getElementById('msgContent').innerHTML = x ;

Comment: Please update the QUESTION with a [mcve] using the `[<>]` stack snippet editor and include example of actual text/HTML and the expected result

Comment: Also it s NOT recommended to manipulate HTML with regex.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/szxupw

I understand the issue now, I am using <a href='$1'>$1</a> , but seems like the regex output is different. is there a way to output whole url as $1 ? 

I am really sorry I do not have time to study regex write now, it also confusing , really hard to understand since all are mix of characters

Comment: UPDATE THE QUESTION PLEASE!!! I need to see your HTML/Text and not GUESS

Comment: can you see the code now?

Comment: Click edit, then scroll down, click "edit above snippet" and add relevant HTML/text

Comment: I have edited the code. can you check now

Comment: That is NOT an example of your string. That is just an example of your regex test. If we could see where the URLs would be sitting, we could make a DOM parsing answer instead of innerHTML processing

Comment: it is my website. I have not finished well yet. however if you can help me to figure converts urls in this string I added in code, then I can handle the rest my self.

Comment: See the changes I made to your code. Feel free to delete afterwards

Comment: wow great. Thank so so much. This is what I wanted